# How to implement timer based on current time in android

Tags: android

I want to implement a timer in my application if user click clock in button timer should start from device time and the timer should run when giving pause timer should pause when user click stop timer should stop, Please help me.

for example, now time is 13:20:10 user click means timer should run on this time not from 00, normal timer code I have, but based on the current time it should run.

Comment: what time you'll show when clicking resume after pausing clock?

Comment: after pause again device time onwards it should run

Answer (score 4):

you can try this. call start()/stop() when you want to start/stop timer. if you want to update UI (Main)Thread use  runOnUiThread(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) or handler for update UI Thread

```
import java.util.Calendar;
int hou=0;
int min=0;
int sec=0;
boolean stopTimer=false;
private void initTimer()
{
    Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    hou=currentTime.getHours();
    min=currentTime.getMinutes();
    sec=currentTime.getSeconds();
    Log.e("Initial Timer ","hou"+hou+ " min"+min+" sec"+sec);
    startTimerThread();
}
private void startTimerThread()
{

    new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {

                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            updateTimer();
        }
    }.start();
}
private void updateTimer()
{
    if(!stopTimer)
    {

        sec=(((++sec)%60)==0)?0:sec;
        min=(sec==0)?(((++min)%60==0)?0:min):min;
        hou=(min==0)?((++hou)):hou;
        /*hou%=12;*/
        Log.e("Update Timer ","hou"+hou+ " min"+min+" sec"+sec);
        startTimerThread();
    }
}
public void start()
{
    initTimer();
}
public void stop()
{
    stopTimer=false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this using by using countdowntimer like this :

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(1000000000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                Log.v(TAG , "CountDownTimer : " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
            }
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        };
        timer.start();
```

on pause you can cancel it like this:

```
timer.cancel();
```

Answer (score 1):

i have take three button, first start button click on device time show in textview and it update as per device time. when click on paused button stop time update. and when click on restart time device time when start to stop.

```
mBtnStartTime?.setOnClickListener {
        val someHandler = Handler(mainLooper)
        someHandler.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                mTvTime?.text = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.US).format(Date())
                someHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
            }
        }, 10)
        mBtnPaused?.setOnClickListener {
            someHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
        }
        mBtnRestart?.setOnClickListener {
            someHandler.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
                override fun run() {
                    mTvTime?.text = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.US).format(Date())
                    someHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
                }
            }, 10)
        }
```